# What is payerId in PayPal iOS sdk

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using PayPal iOS sdk . But I am totally confused about payerID. What is this and how to works. Given that it may be email or unique identifier . Can I make it hardcoded like **XYZ@gmail.com** for every payer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nikhil Chaurasiya, Dave from PayPal here.

Here is the relevant bit from `PayPalPaymentViewController.h`:

```
///    If payerId is nil, then PayPalPaymentViewController will treat the user as a one-time "guest":
///    - if the user logs into their PayPal account, then at the completion of their
///      transaction they will be logged back out; subsequent payments will require fresh logins.
///    - if the user pays with a credit card, that credit card information will not be "remembered"
///      for subsequent payments.
```

So if you do not know whether the user is the same one who last used the app, you should provide `nil` for `payerId`.

On the other hand, if you have a definite way of identifying the user (such as the user's email address), then you would provide that identifying string each time in `payerId`. The result would then be that the user's PayPal login or their credit card information *would* be remembered from one transaction to the next.

If in doubt, the safest approach is to pass `nil` for `payerId`.